# Recuperar parte específica de um objeto javascript em um função AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Preciso recuperar um atributo de um objeto pelo AJAX em um $.each(), e passar ele na src de uma tag de img.

Função AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: `user/album/recommended/`,
        context: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            data = JSON.parse(data); 
            console.log(data);
            var cont = 1;
            $.each(data, function(index, value){
                $("#album"+cont+"").append('<img src="'+value.data.cover_medium+'"/>');
                cont++;
            });
            $(".new-album").show();
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('Erro no AJAX de recomendação');
        },
    });
```

console.log(data) retorna isso:

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você esta fazendo o $.each de forma incorreta

```
$.each(data.data, function(index, value){
   $("#album"+cont+"").append('<img src="'+value.cover_medium+'"/>');
   cont++;
});
```

Comment: Poderiam me explicar o motivo do negativo?